# app da erro 404 ou erro 0

Tags: ajax, apache-cordova, app

Estou tentando criar um app usando jquery, css, html e compilando via phonegap

Ao rodar via browser(http://www.petnetweb.online/shop/) aparecem os dados, porém, ao compilar e rodar via app no android não aparece o valor 0

Observei que o console do Chrome exibe:

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.petnetweb.online/shop/gets/getdiversos.php' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Inseri o seguinte abaixo mas nao resolveu

```
VER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] == "http://petnetweb.online/") {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://petnetweb.online/');
    header('Content-type: application/xml');
    readfile('arunerDotNetResource.xml');
}
```

**Código que faz a consulta**

```
<script>
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp;
obj = { "table":"customers", "limit":20 };
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("getrecseupet").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    } else{document.getElementById("getrecseupet").innerHTML =this.status}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.petnetweb.online/shop/gets/getrecseupet.php" , true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

É um erro de CORS, está explícito na mensagem de erro no console do Chrome.

Ao rodar local, você tem que adicionar a url `http://localhost` (ou *) ao header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Sugiro dar uma estudada sobre o que é e como funciona o CORS:

- https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/o-que-e-cors-e-como-resolver-os-principais-erros/amp/
- https://medium.com/@alexandremjacques/entendendo-o-cors-parte-8331d0a777e1